# Changing font of any website inside webView

Tags: java, android-studio

So I made "browser" in android studio.
I have defined webView in MainActivity

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
```

My webView is loading pages with this part of code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    if(!NetworkState.connectionAvailable(MainActivity.this)){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.check_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {

                        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        String link = kreirajLink();
                        webView.loadUrl(link.trim());
                        //editText.setText("");
                    }

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }
        });

private String kreirajLink(){
        String link = editText.getText().toString();
        //Provjeri da li je link ispravan
        if(link.contains("http://") || link.contains("https://")){
            return link;
        }
        if(link.contains("www.")){
            link = "https://" + link.trim();
            return link;
        }
        //Kreiraj google link
        String[] elements = link.split(" ");
        String linkCreator = "";
        for (String x : elements){
            linkCreator = linkCreator.trim() + x.trim() + "+";
        }
        if ((linkCreator != null) && (linkCreator.length() > 0)) {
            linkCreator = linkCreator.substring(0, linkCreator.length() - 1);
        }
        link = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + linkCreator.trim();
        editText.setText("");
        return link;
    }
```

I have custom fonts imported in android studio (@fonts/....).

Is it possible to change font of any website opened with webView, for example that if user go on "www.facebook.com" or "www.cnn.com" text font on those sites be custom (Imported in android studio in ttf format).

Only solution that I see right now is to download specific site as html and change font but that would take too much time to load some webpages.

Comment: doubtful, since font-family is declared in css/html. why would you want to view sites in a way they're not supposed to be viewed and might mess with the layout?

Comment: I am currently working on some project that requires that (humanitarian purposes, people with disabilities) and this would be the best solution if possible.